# How can I install drivers for my USB wifi adapter if I have no internet?

Tags: networking, drivers, usb

On Ubuntu, no wifi adapters are found. The reason I'm making this post and not just following the 2 million other threads with the same problem is because everyone on them has a built in wifi adapter. On my device, I have some random USB adapter that isn't showing up in Linux. I'm not sure if that changes anything, but I want to check. My main issue is that I can't get the drivers for it without the internet. I'm writing this on a separate device. I don't even know if drivers would change anything so please assist me. Thank you!

Comment: In order to get help please avoid rants, ridiculous exaggerations, etc. and instead provide useful information for those who can help you with that. No, USB or internal is not the issue. Please run `lsusb` in terminal and post the relevant line that identifies your hardware. Then we'll see what can be done.

Answer (score 0):

The Ubuntu Desktop installer provides a "Try Ubuntu" environment specifically so you can test that your hardware ...including WiFi adapter... works with Ubuntu before committing to an install.

You have options to connect to the network other ways: You can use an ethernet cable, or your can tether your phone, or you can simply borrow a friend's Wi-Fi adapter for the afternoon.

The specific failure of no-wifi-driver-found-for-your device may have two causes:

1. Kernel modules (drivers) are contributed to the Linux kernel by the device manufacturer. If you installed an older release of Ubuntu, that contribution may not have occurred yet -- the easiest solution is to try a newer release of Ubuntu.
2. A few shoddy manufacturers never bother to contribute the modules for their hardware at all -- the easiest solution is to return or exchange that dongle for properly supported hardware.

Compiling and installing your own kernel modules (drivers) is usually (not always) possible, and does indeed require internet access. It requires a great deal of source code. It requires a bit of training -- it's not for beginners. That method went out of fashion almost 20 years ago when installing using software packages supplanted it. It's not considered a serious method of supporting popular software today.

Today, "Linux support" means the modules are already included in the Linux Kernel. Anything else I would consider a fraudulent claim or a con.